# gcc: local include path hides system header file

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, cmake, g++

I have a local file `endian.h` which declares some byte-swapping functions.

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>

inline uint16_t bswap(uint16_t val) { return __builtin_bswap16(val); }
inline uint32_t bswap(uint32_t val) { return __builtin_bswap32(val); }
...
```

It seems the include paths CMake generates in my makefiles are causing `/usr/include/endian.h` to be hidden from `/usr/include/ctype.h`, instead resolving to `./src/foo/endian.h`

```
In file included from /usr/include/ctype.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/cctype:42,
                 ...
                 from ./src/foo/session.h:3

./endian.h: In function ‘uint32_t bswap(uint32_t)’:
./endian.h:17:36: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint32_t bswap(uint32_t)’
  inline uint32_t bswap(uint32_t val) { return __builtin_bswap32(val); }
```

One of the include paths is the current directory, the same one in which my `endian.h` file is: `-I ./src/foo`

It is this path which causes `/usr/include/endian.h` to be hidden

**Works:**

```
g++ -I./src ./src/foo/session.cpp
```

**Broken:**

```
g++ -I./src -I./src/foo ./src/foo/session.cpp
```

I was under the (clearly wrong) impression that *angle-bracket* includes searched the system paths, whilst *quote* includes searched the paths specified using `-I`.

With the include path `-I./src`, if I `#include "bar/bar.h"` from `./src/foo/foo.h`, that works, even though it's not local to the `foo` subdirectory (ie: it finds `bar/bar.h` using the `-I./src` include path), which I suppose explains my impression about what each include type meant.

However, it seems these also affect how system includes are found (or at least, how *angle bracket* includes are found). Is that correct?

Without forcing me to rename my local `endian.h` file, is the only way to resolve this to remove that include path?

Comment: "" are for relative to the current source file, <> are relative to all entries in include path.

Comment: endian.h is part of Linux, maybe use a more sane name.

Comment: @usr1234567 how come it works when I use `""` to a file that *isn't* relative to the current source file?

Comment: @usr1234567 are you suggesting that there can only ever be one instance of a file with a name for things to be considered sane? IMHO that sounds more insane than sane?

Comment: Avoiding name clashes is sane. It rules out a whole bunch of errors which might get difficult to detect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what the gcc manual says about include search order:

> The lookup order is as follows:
>
> 1. For the quote form of the include directive, the directory of the current file is searched first.
> 2. For the quote form of the include directive, the directories specified by -iquote options are searched in left-to-right order, as
>      they appear on the command line.
> 3. Directories specified with -I options are scanned in left-to-right order.
> 4. Directories specified with -isystem options are scanned in left-to-right order.
> 5. Standard system directories are scanned.
> 6. Directories specified with -idirafter options are scanned in left-to-right order.

As you can see, files inlcuded by the `-I` option (3) are searched before standard system directories (5) (which includes `/usr/include`).

So in general, files in directories you add with `-I` will hide system headers of the same name, regardless of whether those are included with `<>` or `""`.

The difference between `""` and `<>` is that files included with `""` *first* search the current directory (and the `-iquote` directories, but that is much more obscure). So if you include a file like `#include "foo/bar.h"` and this file includes "endian.h", then if `foo/endian.h` exists it will be used rather than a file by the same name from the standard include directories. However, if you `#include <endian.h>` the system version will be used. In that way, unintended name collisions are reduced in both direction if you use the correct quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Initially there were a distinction between `""` and `<>` indeed. But, right now, as far as I know, all major compilers treat both equally. There's really no difference between them as far as how compiler treats them. It's by convention that people are using these notations. 
`endian.h` is a standard header, common name. You should probably move it one folder down to avoid name collision, something like `"myProject/endian.h"` or change the name to a more definitive one.

Comment: They are not equal at all: files included with `""` will look in the current directory first, so once you include a specific file, it can find all its siblings (and "nephews" etc) automatically if you use the `""` form. The `<>` disables that, so it is appropriate for system header files that you expect to find from the standard search paths.